# Get number of rows if equal to zero - DB2

Tags: c#, for-loop, db2

I am trying to see if a record exists in the database by counting the rows. I have code which counts the number of rows and returns the number of rows (1,2,3 etc) so that record exists in the database. Is there away to count the rows but only return a message if the number of rows equal 0 (so the record doesn't exist in the database)?

```
while (dbReader.Read())
                {
                    int fCount = dbReader.FieldCount;
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < fCount; i2++)
{
     string col = dbReader.GetString(i2);

      string strExist = "Record Exists";
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + strExist + "');", true); 
}
}
Some Code --- 
{
    // Record doesn't exist in database.
}
```

I'm using C# with DB2 database.

When I do an If statement

```
if fcount == 0,
```

after I debug it, it states Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No data exists for the row/column. On line string col = dbReader.GetString(i2);

I know the data doesn't exist but instead I want a message not this error.

Comment: Your example is a little brief and I don't know what you mean by 'return a message'.  Does fCount contain the number of rows?  So don't you just need if (fCount == 0)?  I think it would help if you added more detail to the question.

Comment: I've changed the code, I hope that helps

Comment: OK, that helps, I was thinking that fCount was a row count, now I can see it is a field count.  The fact you've got into the loop means you must have one row of data or the Read would return False.  The exception you're getting implies that there isn't data for one of your columns.  You could try if `(!dbReader.IsDBNull(i2))` before trying to call `GetString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you simply looking at `dbReader.HasRows()`?

Counting fields seems to be a poor way to count rows...

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if the OP is trying to check for empty rows or empty fields.  If it is just checking for zero rows then HasRows is the right answer.

Comment: I have used this 
    if (dbReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        
                    }
                    else if (dbReader.HasRows == false)
                    {
                        
                    }
The true statement works fine but if the record doesnt exist the false statement never runs

Comment: Correction - It seems to working fine for some reason now. HasRows() works perfectly. Thank You